# Trouble combining if / else with .click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, if-statement

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.frontpageimg').click(function(){
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
        });
        if('.frontpageimg').data('clicked') {
            $('#imagepos').slideUp(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            $('#contentpos').slideUp(2000).fadeIn(2000);
        } else {
            $('#imagepos').delay(8000).slideUp(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            $('#contentpos').delay(8000).slideUp(2000).fadeIn(5000);
        }
    });
```

The website animates to show the main content after a delay, which is what's supposed to happen. However, I want the user to be able to skip waiting and activate a shorter animation by clicking on an image. Currently everything under the 'else' part works, but nothing happens when the image is clicked.

EDIT: I've changed the code in an attempt to get things working, still doesn't do what I want it to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#imagepos').delay(8000).slideUp(2000).fadeOut(2000);
        $('#contentpos').delay(8000).slideUp(2000).fadeIn(5000);    
    });
    $('#frontpageimg').click(function(){
                $('div:animated').stop();
                $('div:animated').clearQueue();
                $('#imagepos').slideUp(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                $('#contentpos').slideUp(2000).fadeIn(2000);
            });
```

Comment: There is a _syntax error_ in your code `if('.frontpageimg')`

Comment: Not sure how anything in the if/else block is working, code execution should stop with an error on the `if` line

Comment: Fixed the syntax error, and moved around a bunch of things before settling with the current attempt. It still doesn't work, but isn't throwing up any errors.

Answer (score 3):

You're binding the click handler within the function (which is only called once, in a single threaded environment) that you are trying to change the behavior of.

You would be better off trying to cancel or modify the animation sequence (if it is still running) from the cluck handler,   alternatively, you could have your animation sequence check to see if the button has been clicked

Comment: Can I use .fadein/out and .slideup in an .animate method?